# How to report a bug against Ubuntu's upgrade process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade

I just upgraded to lucid and discovered a nasty bug. It prevents the system from booting and took me hours to resolve. Now I'd like to report it along with the workaround I found. The only problem is: Where? Other such bugs have been filed against "update-manager", but that's just the GUI calling some scripts which do the real work. so what do I do?

What should I substitute for XYZ in

```
ubuntu-bug XYZ
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug should be filed against update-manager as stated here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage#When%20upgrading%20Ubuntu%20%28or%20derivatives%29